# How do I make a 180° spiral staircase? (specific measurements)

Tags: bezier-curves

I'm looking to create a 180° spiral staircase with a step width of 1.28m; step height of either 16cm or 8cm, and step depth of 32cm (inner) and 64cm (outer). This model will be inside, thus the player shall never see its backfaces. How can I make this model with exact measurements? I ask because I hate curves.

Any help would be much appreciated ♥

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos it can't be a duplicate, those are different measurements... ;-)

Comment: @cegaton we should open stairs.stackexchange with all possible dimension combinations as answers :)